# Windows 10 activation issue after changing hard disk to new computer

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I purchased a new computer which has windows 8.1 pre installed. However, in order to keep my old data and software I took my old SSD hard drive over to my new computer. The hard disk has windows 10 installed, from a previous upgrade. Now Windows is asking me to activate and enter a product key.

How can I get a product key? I have basically paid twice for windows, once on my old and once on my new computer. I can hardly be expected to purchase windows a third time. Who can I get a product key?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chatted with Microsoft support and they eventually gave me a new product key. It was necessary to chat to a supervisor and explain to them that I had a faulty motherboard that was exchanged

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is the the Windows OS in the old hard disk was activated on a different PC and hence is tied to a different hardware.

The new PC had Windows 8.1 and the activation is tied to the new PC.

I would suggest that you re-attach the new HDD, upgrade the OS to Windows 10, let it activate successfully and then swap the HDD. This may allow you to keep your old OS files and have Windows activated. If it does not you will have to re-install Windows 10 on your SSD after you upgrade the Windows 8 OS.

if you don't want to try this, try calling up Microsoft Support and explain them your problem. May be they will just give you a new Activation key.

Comment: Why would I have to go through all the hassle? Surely Microsoft would need to understand my situation. But they only have support people in India that hardly speak any English .

Comment: @Nicolas For a matter of fact, I am an Indian. That does not mean we do not know how to speak English. What you want to do is not something that is regularly done but you can try convincing the support personnel or write a mail to Microsoft Support explaining your situation

Comment: OEM Windows is tied to the hardware which it was originally installed on for Life. I doubt they will change that rule for you but you can try,